# Rails show/store values in url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, routes

After i submit a form I want to store some of the submitted values in my new url (to the page I was redirected to).

For example:

```
www.someurl.com/myproject?limit=10
```

I have tried

```
patient_record_path(limit: 10)
```

but that doesn't seem to work

I get the error:
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"patient_record", :limit=>10}

EDIT: So I changed it to

```
patient_record_path(id: 1, limit: 10)
```

This renders however it doesn't display these values to the url

rake routes

```
  patient_record_index GET    /patient_record(.:format)            patient_record#index
                       POST   /patient_record(.:format)            patient_record#create
new_patient_record GET    /patient_record/new(.:format)        patient_record#new
   edit_patient_record GET    /patient_record/:id/edit(.:format)   patient_record#edit
    patient_record GET    /patient_record/:id(.:format)        patient_record#show
                   PUT    /patient_record/:id(.:format)        patient_record#update
                   DELETE /patient_record/:id(.:format)        patient_record#destroy
```

Comment: What doesn't work? limit=10 isn't being carried over?

Comment: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"patient_record", :limit=>10}

Comment: print 'rake routes', and show us the relevant routes

Comment: Try patient_record_path(1, :limit => 10)

Comment: that didnt work. am i correct to putting that line at the end of my controller?

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, we are trying to view a single patient_record ?

Comment: no in my create.html i have a form that displays results.  I want to be able to see the values of the params (limit) that i input into the form

Comment: to be honest, your naming convention doesn't seem like the rails way, which is confusing. you shouldnt be rendering anything with the create action. You shouldn't have a create.html. the create action accepts the POST, and then either redirects or renders the "new" action.

Answer (score 0):

use "params.merge" to keep previous parameters. e.g.

`<%= link_to 'Link', params.merge({:per_page => 20}) %>`